# Batch Training Accuracy is always multiple of 10%

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

So I am training a CNN and compute the training accuracy for each batch. Most of the it gives out 100% batch training accuracy. which I though was okay because I'm testing my model against the data I trained it with. But at some iterations, I get a 90% or 90% batch training accuracy. And worst, sometimes it goes down to 0% real quick and bounces back to 100% batch training accuracy. And I used the algorithm in https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/04_Save_Restore.ipynb and they also computed the batch training accuracy but they don't get the same results I get. They started out with around 80% batch training accuracy and observed a gradual increase until 98%. Why is this?

I was suspecting that my network is overfitting.

Here is my exact code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
import pyfftw
from scipy import signal
import xlrd
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import math
import os
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

##matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')


## define funtions
def read_data(file_path):
##    column_names = ['user-id','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
    column_names = ['activity','timestamp', 'Ax', 'Ay', 'Az', 'Gx', 'Gy', 'Gz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz'] ## 3 sensors
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path,header = None, names = column_names)
    return data

def feature_normalize(dataset):
    mu = np.mean(dataset,axis = 0)
    sigma = np.std(dataset,axis = 0)
    return (dataset - mu)/sigma

def plot_axis(ax, x, y, title):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_ylim([min(y) - np.std(y), max(y) + np.std(y)])
    ax.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
    ax.grid(True)

def plot_activity(activity,data):
    fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, figsize = (15, 10), sharex = True)
    plot_axis(ax0, data['timestamp'], data['Ax'], 'x-axis')
    plot_axis(ax1, data['timestamp'], data['Ay'], 'y-axis')
    plot_axis(ax2, data['timestamp'], data['Az'], 'z-axis')
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
    fig.suptitle(activity)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)
    plt.show()

def windows(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < data.count():
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)

def segment_signal(data, window_size = None, num_channels=None): # edited
    segments = np.empty((0,window_size,num_channels)) #change from 3 to 9 channels for AGM fusion #use variable num_channels=9
    labels = np.empty((0))
    for (n_start, n_end) in windows(data['timestamp'], window_size):
##        x = data["x-axis"][start:end]
##        y = data["y-axis"][start:end]
##        z = data["z-axis"][start:end]
        n_start = int(n_start)
        n_end = int(n_end)
        Ax = data["Ax"][n_start:n_end]
        Ay = data["Ay"][n_start:n_end]
        Az = data["Az"][n_start:n_end]
        Gx = data["Gx"][n_start:n_end]
        Gy = data["Gy"][n_start:n_end]
        Gz = data["Gz"][n_start:n_end]
        Mx = data["Mx"][n_start:n_end]
        My = data["My"][n_start:n_end]
        Mz = data["Mz"][n_start:n_end]
        if(len(dataset['timestamp'][n_start:n_end]) == window_size): # include only windows with size of 90
            segments = np.vstack([segments,np.dstack([Ax,Ay,Az,Gx,Gy,Gz,Mx,My,Mz])])
            labels = np.append(labels,stats.mode(data["activity"][n_start:n_end])[0][0])
    return segments, labels

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape = shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def depthwise_conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x,W, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

def apply_depthwise_conv(x,weights,biases):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.add(depthwise_conv2d(x, weights),biases))

def apply_max_pool(x,kernel_size,stride_size):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 1, kernel_size, 1], 
                          strides=[1, 1, stride_size, 1], padding='VALID') 

#------------------------get dataset----------------------#

## run shoaib_dataset.py to generate dataset_shoaib_total.txt

## get data from dataset_shoaib_total.txt
dataset = read_data('dataset_shoaib_total.txt')


#--------------------preprocessing------------------------#

dataset['Ax'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Ax'])
dataset['Ay'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Ay'])
dataset['Az'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Az'])
dataset['Gx'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Gx'])
dataset['Gy'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Gy'])
dataset['Gz'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Gz'])
dataset['Mx'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Mx'])
dataset['My'] = feature_normalize(dataset['My'])
dataset['Mz'] = feature_normalize(dataset['Mz'])


###--------------------plot activity data----------------#

##for activity in np.unique(dataset["activity"]):
##    subset = dataset[dataset["activity"] == activity][:180]
##    plot_activity(activity,subset)


#------------------fixed hyperparameters--------------------#

window_size = 200 #from 90 #FIXED at 4 seconds


#----------------input hyperparameters------------------#

input_height = 1
input_width = window_size
num_labels = 6
num_channels = 9 #from 3 channels #9 channels for AGM


#-------------------sliding time window----------------#

segments, labels = segment_signal(dataset, window_size=window_size, num_channels=num_channels)
labels = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype = np.int8)
reshaped_segments = segments.reshape(len(segments), (window_size*num_channels)) #use variable num_channels instead of constant 3 channels


#------------divide data into test and training set-----------#

train_test_split = np.random.rand(len(reshaped_segments)) < 0.80
train_x_init = reshaped_segments[train_test_split]
train_y_init = labels[train_test_split]
test_x = reshaped_segments[~train_test_split]
test_y = labels[~train_test_split]

train_validation_split = np.random.rand(len(train_x_init)) < 0.80
train_x = train_x_init[train_validation_split]
train_y = train_y_init[train_validation_split]
validation_x = train_x_init[~train_validation_split]
validation_y = train_y_init[~train_validation_split]


#---------------training hyperparameters----------------#

batch_size = 10
kernel_size = 60 #from 60 #optimal 2
depth = 15 #from 60 #optimal 15
num_hidden = 1000 #from 1000 #optimal 80

learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 8

total_batches = train_x.shape[0] ##// batch_size


#---------define placeholders for input----------#

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,input_width * num_channels], name="input")
X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X,[-1,input_height,input_width,num_channels])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,num_labels])


#---------------------perform convolution-----------------#

# first convolutional layer 
c_weights = weight_variable([1, kernel_size, num_channels, depth])
c_biases = bias_variable([depth * num_channels])

c = apply_depthwise_conv(X_reshaped,c_weights,c_biases)
p = apply_max_pool(c,20,2)

# second convolutional layer
c2_weights = weight_variable([1, 6,depth*num_channels,depth//10])
c2_biases = bias_variable([(depth*num_channels)*(depth//10)])

c = apply_depthwise_conv(p,c2_weights,c2_biases)


#--------------flatten data for fully connected layers----------#

shape = c.get_shape().as_list()
c_flat = tf.reshape(c, [-1, shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])


#------------fully connected layers----------------#

f_weights_l1 = weight_variable([shape[1] * shape[2] * depth * num_channels * (depth//10), num_hidden])
f_biases_l1 = bias_variable([num_hidden])
f = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(c_flat, f_weights_l1),f_biases_l1))


#----------------------dropout------------------#

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
drop_layer = tf.nn.dropout(f, keep_prob)


#----------------------softmax layer----------------#

out_weights = weight_variable([num_hidden, num_labels])
out_biases = bias_variable([num_labels])
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(drop_layer, out_weights),out_biases), name="y_")


#-----------------loss optimization-------------#

loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(y_))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss)


#-----------------compute accuracy---------------#

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,1), tf.argmax(Y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#-------------early stopping-----------------#

# Best validation accuracy seen so far.
best_validation_accuracy = 0.0

# Iteration-number for last improvement to validation accuracy.
last_improvement = 0

# Stop optimization if no improvement found in this many iterations.
require_improvement = 1000

# Counter for total number of iterations performed so far.
total_iterations = 0

def validation_accuracy():
    return session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: validation_x, Y: validation_y, keep_prob: 1.0})

def next_batch(b, batch_size, train_x, train_y):
    ##for b in range(total_batches):    
    offset = (b * batch_size) % (train_y.shape[0] - batch_size)
    batch_x = train_x[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_y = train_y[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    return batch_x, batch_y

def optimize(num_iterations):
    # Ensure we update the global variables rather than local copies.
    global total_iterations
    global best_validation_accuracy
    global last_improvement

    # Start-time used for printing time-usage below.
    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(num_iterations):

        # Increase the total number of iterations performed.
        # It is easier to update it in each iteration because
        # we need this number several times in the following.
        total_iterations += 1

        # Get a batch of training examples.
        # x_batch now holds a batch of images and
        # y_true_batch are the true labels for those images.
        ##x_batch, y_true_batch = data.train.next_batch(train_batch_size)
        x_batch, y_true_batch = next_batch(i, batch_size, train_x, train_y)

        # Put the batch into a dict with the proper names
        # for placeholder variables in the TensorFlow graph.
        feed_dict_train = {X: x_batch,
                           Y: y_true_batch, keep_prob: 0.5}

        # Run the optimizer using this batch of training data.
        # TensorFlow assigns the variables in feed_dict_train
        # to the placeholder variables and then runs the optimizer.
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

        # Print status every 100 iterations and after last iteration.
        if (total_iterations % 100 == 0) or (i == (num_iterations - 1)):

            # Calculate the accuracy on the training-batch.
            acc_train = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: x_batch,
                           Y: y_true_batch, keep_prob: 1.0})

            # Calculate the accuracy on the validation-set.
            # The function returns 2 values but we only need the first.
            ##acc_validation, _ = validation_accuracy()
            acc_validation = validation_accuracy()

            # If validation accuracy is an improvement over best-known.
            if acc_validation > best_validation_accuracy:
                # Update the best-known validation accuracy.
                best_validation_accuracy = acc_validation

                # Set the iteration for the last improvement to current.
                last_improvement = total_iterations

                # Save all variables of the TensorFlow graph to file.
                saver.save(sess=session, save_path="../shoaib-har_agm_es.ckpt")

                # A string to be printed below, shows improvement found.
                improved_str = '*'
            else:
                # An empty string to be printed below.
                # Shows that no improvement was found.
                improved_str = ''

            # Status-message for printing.
            msg = "Iter: {0:>6}, Train-Batch Accuracy: {1:>6.1%}, Validation Acc: {2:>6.1%} {3}"

            # Print it.
            print(msg.format(i + 1, acc_train, acc_validation, improved_str))

        # If no improvement found in the required number of iterations.
        if total_iterations - last_improvement > require_improvement:
            print("No improvement found in a while, stopping optimization.")

            # Break out from the for-loop.
            break

    # Ending time.
    end_time = time.time()

    # Difference between start and end-times.
    time_dif = end_time - start_time

    # Print the time-usage.
    print("Time usage: " + str(timedelta(seconds=int(round(time_dif)))))


optimize(10000)
```

With the output:

[image]

What exactly is training accuracy? Is it even computed? Or do you compute the training accuracy on the entire training data and not just the batch you trained your network with?

[image]

Here I printed the results such that it prints out the batch training accuracy and the training accuracy on the entire dataset set for every multiples of 20 iterations.

Comment: Your code and the messages you provided do not match. The print messages in your code have {:1f} which means only one decimal is printed, that's why they look like multiples of 10.

Comment: No, because I tried printing with more decimal places and still the same results

Comment: You still need to update the code, I don't think we are seeing the real code. What is the size of your training and testing sets as well?

Comment: Do you think that this is because I'm using a small batch size? I'm not sure if my model undefitting or overfitting because the batch accuracy is sometimes `100% and somtimes 0%.

Comment: You see, even if I use the above code it will still give out the same result because the precision is based on the percent value and not the decimal value.

Comment: The entire dataset is 44k samples. I divided to to 80-20 training and test and further divided the training data into 80-20 split for training-validation

Comment: Please refer to the new image I added.

Comment: The batch size is 10, that means that all per-batch accuracies can only be multiples of 10%, increase it to something much bigger and you will see different accuracies per batch. Also you can only detect overfitting when the training accuracy is high but the validation accuracy is low. Nobody shows per-batch accuracy, what is important is training/validation accuracy AFTER each epoch.

Comment: You're correct! What methods do you suggest to increase generalization accuracy?

Comment: You can use a rolling or lambda average over the training accuracy and even if you keep a batch size of 10, with a large enough lambda you'll get a very good running average accuracy

Comment: Hi @wontonimo could you provide more detail and reference for this solution? This is the first time I heard about this

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay  .  One way to implement lambda average is like this **lambda_average = lambda * lambda_average + ( 1 - lambda ) * new_value** where lambda is a value in the range of [0.0,1.0].  A lambda of .9 would mean that 90% of the average comes from the previous average and 10% comes from the last value.  You can google "rolling average calculation" to find out more about rolling average calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The data is divided to 3 sets: **train**, **validation** and **test**.

Batch training accuracy is computed on the train set (the difference between the label and the prediction).

Validation accuracy is the accuracy on the validation set.

The batch accuracy can be computed just after a forward pass in the network. The number of samples in one forward pass is the batch size. It is just a way to train models faster (mini-batch gradient descent)

Overfitting is when the model works really good on known data (training set) but performs poorly on new data.

As to the 10% multiples, it is just the printing format you are using.

Comment: "Batch training accuracy is computed on the train set (the difference between the label and the prediction)." What do you mean by this? So just after you feed your batch to train the network you compute the accuracy on that same batch? I did it in my code and I got these results. Why is this?

Comment: The training accuracy is the accuracy on the validation set? So there is no validation accuracy?

Comment: So getting the accuracy on the same batch you trained with during that iteration will not necessarily yield to 100%? Are the results I'm getting acceptable?

Comment: My data is sensor signals from smartphone.. hmm what do you suggest that I do? It's really odd that i get multiples of 10% (100%, 90%, 70%, 0%) for the batch training accuracy. Why is this?

Comment: You used this formatting {1:>6.1%} when printing the Batch Training Accuracy, so it is just 1.0%,0.9%,0.7%,0.0%, therefore it is not very significant fluctuations.

Comment: It's still the same. I used a different code to display the above results but still the same result. Also, is it acceptable that the batch accuracy changes inconsistently instead of steadily increasing in value?

Comment: It is known that mini-batch gradient descent has fluctuations. But this is already a different question...